# What are the quantum dimensions of the primary fields for $SU(N)$ level-$k$ Kac-Moody current algebras?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, research-level, affine-lie-algebra

The CFT of the [$\mathrm{SU}(N)$ level $k$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wess%E2%80%93Zumino%E2%80%93Witten_model) Kac-Moody current algebra has many Kac-Moody primary fields. I wonder if any one has calculated the quantum dimensions of those Kac-Moody primary fields.

I know that, for $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ level $k$ Kac-Moody current algebra, there is a general expression for the quantum dimensions of the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ primary fields.

Comment: Maybe http://www.nikhef.nl/~t58/Site/Kac.html this could be helpful. It gives pretty much everything one needs to know about WZW CFTs, although not fully analytically.

Comment: Note: Also [posted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/207780).

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice data base on Web. For example https://www.math.ksu.edu/~gerald/voas/mtc/kmA3_3.html list the data for SU(4) level 3 case.

Answer (score 1):

The S matrix of affine Lie algebra can be calculated by the [Kac-Peterson formula](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000187088490032X), which can also be found in Theorem 13.8 in [Kac's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-1382-4).